# json request from rails API returning an error code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to have rails render some json. When I go to mysite.com/v1/discussions.json I'm expecting to see a print out of all the Discussions in the database. However instead when I go there I get the error "{"status":"error","code":404,"message":"Not found"}". I can't figure out why I'm not getting the json response I expect.

I'm using rails 5.

/controllers/api/v1/discussions_controller.rb

```
module Api
    module V1
        class DiscussionsController < ApplicationController
            respond_to :json

            def index
                respond_with Discussion.all
            end

            def show
                respond_with Discussion.find(params[:id])
            end

            def create
                @discussion = Discussion.new(discussion_params)

                @discussion.save
                render json: @discussion, status: :created
            end

            def update
                respond_with Discussion.update(params[:id], params[:discussion])
            end

            def destroy
                @discussion = Discussion.where(id: params[:id]).first

                if @discussion.destroy
                head(:ok)
                else
                head(:unprocessable_entity)
                end
            end


            private
            def discussion_params
              params.require(:discussion).permit(:title, :user_id, :content, :channel_id, :host_stance, :live, :archive, :private, :tag1, :tag2, :tag3, :tag4, :opponent_stance, :against, :competitive )
            end

        end
    end
end
```

/config/routes.rb

```
  namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :discussions
      resources :users
      resources :sessions, only: [:create, :destroy]
    end
  end
```

/controllers/api_controller.rb

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController 
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
end
```

Comment: do you mind pasting the request you get in the rails console ?, the one that tells you the params and the controller#action being executed.

Comment: Try `mysite.com/api/v1/discussions.json`

Comment: Have you tried just /v1/discussions ?

Comment: I've tried /api/v1/discussions & api/v1/discussions.json both return the same error.

Comment: Do you have any `before_action` or `after_action` callbacks in you `application_controller.rb`?

Comment: yeah I have `before_action :channel_variable

  def channel_variable
    @channels = Channel.all.order('created_at desc')
  end
`  and
 `after_action :track_action
    def track_action
    ahoy.track "Ran action", request.path_parameters
  end`
but i don't see how these would interfere with the api calls.

Comment: Would you post the detailed message that shows in the console log?

Comment: Have you tried `rake routes` to see all the paths your apps has?